# Need Word VBA code to move cursor to end of first column in two-column page layout

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word VB macro that automatically inserts a Visio drawing in a two-column layout. The code works well, but I would like to further automate the process. To do so, I am looking specifically for code that will move the cursor to the end of the first column of the selected page. This column typically does not already have a column break, so my solution can't involve searching for column breaks. And I believe I already have code that selects the current page, just not the end of the first column on that page.

I am able to move the cursor to the end of the page programmatically, and I am able to move the cursor to the top of the page programmatically. I just can't get the cursor to move to the end of the first column of text. All of the online examples I've found so far focus on moving to the end of a column in a table, but not to the end of a column of text in a two-column layout.

10/15/2019: Here's an example page as requested by @cindym

[SamplePage][1]

The document may be several pages long. My current macro works well and meets company requirements for this kind of document, but it requires the user to place the cursor where they want the two-column graphic inserted. I want to make the process more automated (check "top" or "bottom" in an existing userform and have the macro place the two-column figure accordingly on the current page).

Again, I am able programmatically move the cursor to the top or bottom of the page just fine, I just can't get the cursor to the end of the first column (the left-hand column on the two-column page). Our code inserts continuous section breaks and works well if it can insert the first of those breaks at the end of the left-hand column of text.

Based in part on CindyM's suggestion, I tried the following for a two-column Visio diagram at the bottom of the current page, but things go wrong after the third line of code. Other than this initial VBA-driven cursor placement problem, the rest of my code works fine (selects the Visio, inserts continuous breaks, inserts a caption for the figure, etc.). Hope this helps clarify. Thanks again!

```
    `ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Page") `Select selects current page` 
    Selection.GoToNext (wdGoToPage)  `cursor at top of page 2`
    Selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1 `cursor now at end of target page`
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdItem  `cursor now in headline, top of page :(`  
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdItem


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR7BF.png
```

Answer (score 0):

As no code was included in the question as a starting point, the following uses `GoTo` to move to a specific page. The assumption is that this position is *not* a newspaper column. Then the equivalent of pressing Alt+Down Arrow *twice* in the UI to move to the next `TextColumn` (newspaper column) is performed, which would be the beginning of the next column *after* the first. The selection is then moved back one character, to put it at the end of the column.

If the top of the page is a newspaper column and the code should move to the end of that column, then remove one of the `Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdItem` lines.

```
Sub MoveToEndOfNextNewspaperColumn()
    Dim goToPageNr As String

    goToPageNr = "1"

    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext, Name:=goToPageNr

    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdItem
    Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdItem

    Selection.MoveEnd Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=-1
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your response. However, it doesn't quite do the job, which likely means that I didn't explain things very well! Also, I am unaware of the difference between a newspaper column and a text column.  
I have code that moves the cursor to the bottom of the current page. But the current page may have a two-columns-wide headline, and a two-column-wide subhead as well. Using "Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdItem followed by .MoveEnd wdCharacter puts the cursor in those headlines, rather than at the bottom of the left-hand column of text (always two cols. of text). Any ideas?

Comment: use the edit link below your question to put the code and the exact description, including a screen shot of such a page, *in the question*. @KRS